# CardLayout class can't open

Tags: java

I am attempting to add opening cover in my program. So I use a card layout.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game extends JFrame{
    public static CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    public static JPanel dasar = new JPanel(cl);
public Game() {
        dasar.add(new Opening(),"Opening");
        dasar.add(new level1(),"Level 1");
        dasar.add(new level2(),"Level 2");
        dasar.add(new level3(),"Level 3");
        dasar.add(new level4(),"Level 4");
        add(dasar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        /*KeyboardListener listener = new KeyboardListener();
        opening();
        addKeyListener(listener);*/    
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Game G = new Game();
        G.setTitle("PuzzleGame");
        G.setSize(800,550);
        G.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        G.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        G.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and I make a opening class like this:

```
class Opening extends JPanel{
public Opening(){
    AudioClip AudioOp = Applet.newAudioClip(this.getClass().getResource("opening.wav"));

    JLabel atasan = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TOP.png")));
    JLabel bawahan = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("btm.png")));
    JLabel nama = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("namakelompok.png")));
    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("background.jpg")));

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel1.add(atasan);
    panel1.add(bawahan);
    panel1.add(nama);
    panel1.add(background);
    add(panel1);
    background.setBounds(0,0,800,550);
    atasan.setBounds(100,50,600,100);
    bawahan.setBounds(232,450,336,46);
    nama.setBounds(194,180,411,205);
}
}
```

Why when I compile this program cant show anything? it's like blank window
give me a suggestion. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: You should check that the resource image files are being found - the getClass().getResource() calls will return null if they cannot be found. If null, you will need to specify the correct path to the images. Lastly, I highly recommend NOT using a null layout

Comment: I agree with @copeg. You will want to break down this non-functioning code into small parts to see exactly what isn't working. In a small program test to see if you are able to get your ImageIcons. In a separate program, do the same for your audio clip. If getting the autoclip resource takes a lot of time, do it in a background thread.

Comment: Consider using CardLayout#show to show the first screen; also, static is not your friend; and neither is the null layout

Answer (score -1):

Move the following into your constructor:

```
    G.setTitle("PuzzleGame");
    G.setSize(800,550);
    G.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    G.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    G.setVisible(true);
```

So your classes and main will look as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game extends JFrame{
    public static CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    public static JPanel dasar = new JPanel(cl);
public Game() {

        super("PuzzleGame");
        this.setSize(800,550);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dasar.add(new Opening(),"Opening");
        dasar.add(new level1(),"Level 1");
        dasar.add(new level2(),"Level 2");
        dasar.add(new level3(),"Level 3");
        dasar.add(new level4(),"Level 4");
        add(dasar,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*KeyboardListener listener = new KeyboardListener();
        opening();
        addKeyListener(listener);*/    
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Game();
    }
}

class Opening extends JPanel{
    public Opening(){
        AudioClip AudioOp = Applet.newAudioClip(this.getClass().getResource("opening.wav"));

        JLabel atasan = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TOP.png")));
        JLabel bawahan = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("btm.png")));
        JLabel nama = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("namakelompok.png")));
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("background.jpg")));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.add(atasan);
        panel1.add(bawahan);
        panel1.add(nama);
        panel1.add(background);
        add(panel1);
        background.setBounds(0,0,800,550);
        atasan.setBounds(100,50,600,100);
        bawahan.setBounds(232,450,336,46);
        nama.setBounds(194,180,411,205);
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps.

Let me know of the outcome

Comment: What is the basis for this recommendation? Why do you think that this will help the user solve his problem?

Comment: As far as I understand, in the Constructor, he is creating a panel and placing certain objects within it. Then calling that constructor, (which now contains those objects) and assigning all of the JFrame attributes in order to display the Frame. I moved it around so that, all of the components are added whilst setting the attributes of the JFrame (example size) and then set visible. It solves his problem, and displays all the attributes. If you don't agree, please do enlighten me as to were I have gone wrong :)

Comment: Yes, changing the location of those calls will in no way solve his problem. I don't know the cause of the problems other than agreeing with copeg, but your recommendations are pretty much guaranteed not to do anything to solve it.